# Writing a fraction class and I cannot figure out these errors

Tags: c++

I'm writing a fraction.cpp and fraction.h that inputs fraction types and does mathematical operations on them. I have a weird error that says "undefined reference", but the reference is defined as far as I can see. There's also a bunch of errors that say "no matching function for call to fraction::outputFormat(fracForm)" and "candidate is" and others. Here is all of my code for reference:
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
#include "fraction.h"

int main()
{
   fraction f0;
   fraction f1;
   cin >> f0;              // input format numerator/denominator, ex 23/9
   cout << "input: " << f0 << endl;     // outputs what was input

// Note the << and >> operators should also work for file streams

//    cin >> f0 >> f1;     // reads 2 fractions, ex 8/5 12/16
   f1.setFraction(17,6);   // 17/6
   cout << f1.getNumerator() << '/' << f1.getDenominator() << endl; // 17/6
   f1.setFraction(-4.75);     // -19/4
   cout << f1.decimalValue() << endl; // outputs -4.75
   fraction f2(4,8);       // 4/8
   fraction f3(2.875);     // 2 7/8
   cout << f3 << endl;     // outputs 2 7/8 (the default output format is mixed)
   cout << f2 << endl;     // outputs 4/8
   fraction f4(16,8);
   cout << f4 << endl;     // outputs 2

   fraction::outputFormat(improper); // set output format to improper fraction
   cout << f4 << endl;     // outputs 16/8
   cout << f3 << endl;     // outputs 23/8
   cout << f1 << endl;     // outputs -19/4

   fraction::outputFormat(decimal); // set output format to decimal value
   cout << f3 << endl;     // outputs 2.875
   cout << f2 << endl;     // outputs 0.5
   cout << f1 << endl;     // outputs -4.75

   fraction::outputFormat(mixed); // set output format back to default mixed
   cout << f3 << endl;     // outputs 2 7/8
   f1.setFraction(-4.75);
   cout << f1 << endl;     // outputs -4 3/4
   cout << f2 << endl;     // outputs 4/8

   fraction f5(12,8);
   fraction::outputFormat(improper);
   cout << f5 << endl;     // outputs 12/8
   f2.reduce();            // convert to lowest terms
   f5.reduce();
   cout << f2 << endl;     // outputs 1/2
   cout << f5 << endl;     // outputs 3/2
   f5.setDenominator(16);  // change denominator and numerator
                           // error if numerator is not a whole number
   cout << f5 << endl;     // outputs 24/16
   f5.setDenominator(22);
   cout << f5 << endl;     // outputs 33/22
   f5.setDenominator(5);   // output error as numerator would have to be 7.5
   cout << f5 << endl;     // outputs 33/22 (fraction remained the same)

   f1 = f3+f2;             // f1 put in lowest terms
   cout << f1 << endl;     // outputs 27/8
   f1 = f3-f2;
   cout << f1 << endl;
   f1 = f3*f2;
   cout << f1 << endl;
   f1 = f3/f2;
   cout << f1 << endl;

   f1 = f3;
   cout << f1 << endl;      // outputs 23/8
   f1 = 7.75;
   f1 = f2 = 7.75;
   cout << f1 << endl;      // outputs 31/4
   cout << setw(6) << f1 << setw(6) << f2 << endl; // outputs  31/4  31/4

   f0.setFraction(31,4);
   if (f0 == f1)
      cout << "correct\n";
   else
      cout << "incorrect\n";
   // all relational operators should work for comparing 2 fractions

   if (f0 == 7.75)
      cout << "correct\n";
   else
      cout << "incorrect\n";
   // all relational operators should work for comparing fraction to double

   f0.setFraction(2);
   if (f0 < 3)
      cout << "correct\n";
   else
      cout << "incorrect\n";
   // all relational operators should work for comparing fraction to int 

   return 0;
}
```

fraction.h

```
#ifndef fraction
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
enum fracForm {improper, mixed, decimal};

class fraction {
    enum fracForm {improper, mixed, decimal};
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, fraction&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, fraction&);
    public:
        fraction();
        fraction(int, int);
        fraction(double);
        void setFraction(int, int);
        void setFraction(double);
        void setDenominator(int);
        int getNumerator() const;
        int getDenominator() const;
        double decimalValue() const;
        static void outputFormat(fracForm);
        void reduce();
        fraction operator+(const fraction&) const;
        fraction operator-(const fraction&) const;
        fraction operator*(const fraction&) const;
        fraction operator/(const fraction&) const;
        bool operator==(const fraction&) const;
        bool operator!=(const fraction&) const;
        bool operator<(const fraction&) const;
        bool operator>(const fraction&) const;
        bool operator<=(const fraction&) const;
        bool operator>=(const fraction&) const;
        fraction operator+(const int) const;
        fraction operator-(const int) const;
        fraction operator*(const int) const;
        fraction operator/(const int) const;
        bool operator==(const int) const;
        bool operator!=(const int) const;
        bool operator<(const int) const;
        bool operator>(const int) const;
        bool operator<=(const int) const;
        bool operator>=(const int) const;
        fraction operator+(const float) const;
        fraction operator-(const float) const;
        fraction operator*(const float) const;
        fraction operator/(const float) const;
        bool operator==(const float) const;
        bool operator!=(const float) const;
        bool operator<(const float) const;
        bool operator>(const float) const;
        bool operator<=(const float) const;
        bool operator>=(const float) const;
        fraction operator+(const double) const;
        fraction operator-(const double) const;
        fraction operator*(const double) const;
        fraction operator/(const double) const;
        bool operator==(const double) const;
        bool operator!=(const double) const;
        bool operator<(const double) const;
        bool operator>(const double) const;
        bool operator<=(const double) const;
        bool operator>=(const double) const;
        string mix();

    private:
        int num, denom;
        static fracForm format;
};

#endif
```

fraction.cpp

```
#include "fraction.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

fraction::fraction() {
    num = 0;
    denom = 1;
}

fraction::fraction(int numerator, int denominator) {
    setFraction(numerator, denominator);
}

fraction::fraction(double deci) {
    setFraction(deci);
}

void fraction::setFraction(int numerator, int denominator){
    num = numerator;
    denom = denominator;
}

void fraction::setFraction(double deci) {
    int decimal = deci;
    denom = 1;
    while (deci != decimal) {
        deci = deci * 10;
        denom = denom * 10;
        decimal = deci;
    }
    num = deci;
    reduce();
}

void fraction::setDenominator(int denominator) {
    int denom2 = denominator;
    int proportion = num * denom2;
    double newProp = proportion / denom;
    int intProp = newProp;
    if (newProp != intProp) {
        try
        {
            throw 20;
        }
        catch (int n)
        {
            cout << "This does not create a fraction with integers." << endl;
        }
    }
    else {num = newProp; denom = denom2;}
}

int fraction::getNumerator() const {
    return num;
}

int fraction::getDenominator() const{
    return denom;
}

double fraction::decimalValue() const {
    double deci = num/denom;
    return deci;
}

void fraction::outputFormat(fracForm fType) {
    format = fType;
}

void fraction::reduce() {
    num = num / __gcd(num, denom);
    denom = denom / __gcd(num, denom);
}

fraction fraction::operator+(const fraction& frac) const {
    return fraction(decimalValue() + frac.decimalValue());
}

fraction fraction::operator-(const fraction& frac) const {
    return fraction(decimalValue() - frac.decimalValue());
}

fraction fraction::operator*(const fraction& frac) const {
    return fraction(decimalValue() * frac.decimalValue());
}

fraction fraction::operator/(const fraction& frac) const {
    return fraction(decimalValue() / frac.decimalValue());
}

bool fraction::operator==(const fraction& frac) const {
    return decimalValue() == frac.decimalValue();
}

bool fraction::operator!=(const fraction& frac) const {
    return decimalValue() != frac.decimalValue();
}

bool fraction::operator<(const fraction& frac) const {
    return decimalValue() < frac.decimalValue();
}

bool fraction::operator>(const fraction& frac) const {
    return decimalValue() > frac.decimalValue();
}

bool fraction::operator<=(const fraction& frac) const {
    return decimalValue() <= frac.decimalValue();
}

bool fraction::operator>=(const fraction& frac) const {
    return decimalValue() >= frac.decimalValue();
}

fraction fraction::operator+(const int frac) const {
    return fraction(decimalValue() + frac);
}

fraction fraction::operator-(const int frac) const {
    return fraction(decimalValue() - frac);
}

fraction fraction::operator*(const int frac) const {
    return fraction(decimalValue() * frac);
}

fraction fraction::operator/(const int frac) const {
    return fraction(decimalValue() / frac);
}

bool fraction::operator==(const int frac) const {
    return decimalValue() == frac;
}

bool fraction::operator!=(const int frac) const {
    return decimalValue() != frac;
}

bool fraction::operator<(const int frac) const {
    return decimalValue() < frac;
}

bool fraction::operator>(const int frac) const {
    return decimalValue() > frac;
}

bool fraction::operator<=(const int frac) const {
    return decimalValue() <= frac;
}

bool fraction::operator>=(const int frac) const {
    return decimalValue() >= frac;
}

fraction fraction::operator+(const float frac) const {
    return fraction(decimalValue() + frac);
}

fraction fraction::operator-(const float frac) const {
    return fraction(decimalValue() - frac);
}

fraction fraction::operator*(const float frac) const {
    return fraction(decimalValue() * frac);
}

fraction fraction::operator/(const float frac) const {
    return fraction(decimalValue() / frac);
}

bool fraction::operator==(const float frac) const {
    return decimalValue() == frac;
}

bool fraction::operator!=(const float frac) const {
    return decimalValue() != frac;
}

bool fraction::operator<(const float frac) const {
    return decimalValue() < frac;
}

bool fraction::operator>(const float frac) const {
    return decimalValue() > frac;
}

bool fraction::operator<=(const float frac) const {
    return decimalValue() <= frac;
}

bool fraction::operator>=(const float frac) const {
    return decimalValue() >= frac;
}

fraction fraction::operator+(const double frac) const {
    return fraction(decimalValue() + frac);
}

fraction fraction::operator-(const double frac) const {
    return fraction(decimalValue() - frac);
}

fraction fraction::operator*(const double frac) const {
    return fraction(decimalValue() * frac);
}

fraction fraction::operator/(const double frac) const {
    return fraction(decimalValue() / frac);
}

bool fraction::operator==(const double frac) const {
    return decimalValue() == frac;
}

bool fraction::operator!=(const double frac) const {
    return decimalValue() != frac;
}

bool fraction::operator<(const double frac) const {
    return decimalValue() < frac;
}

bool fraction::operator>(const double frac) const {
    return decimalValue() > frac;
}

bool fraction::operator<=(const double frac) const {
    return decimalValue() <= frac;
}

bool fraction::operator>=(const double frac) const {
    return decimalValue() >= frac;
}

fraction::mix() {
    int integer = 0;
    int n = num;
    while (num > denom) {
        num = num - denom;
        integer = integer + 1;
    }
    return to_string(integer) + " " + to_string(num) + "/" + to_string(denom);
}

istream& operator>>(istream& in, fraction& frac) {
    in >> frac.num;
    char i;
    in >> i;
    in >> frac.denom;
    return i;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, fraction& frac) {
    switch (frac.format) {
        case improper: 
            out << to_string(frac.getNumerator()) + "/" + to_string(frac.getDenominator()); break;
        case decimal: 
            out << frac.decimalValue(); break;
        case mixed: 
            out << frac.mix(); break;
    }
}
```

Here are the specific errors:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:27:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘fraction::outputFormat(fracForm)’
    fraction::outputFormat(improper); // set output format to improper fraction
                                   ^
In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
fraction.h:27:21: note: candidate: static void fraction::outputFormat(fraction::fracForm)
         static void outputFormat(fracForm);
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
fraction.h:27:21: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘fracForm’ to ‘fraction::fracForm’
main.cpp:32:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘fraction::outputFormat(fracForm)’
    fraction::outputFormat(decimal); // set output format to decimal value
                                  ^
In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
fraction.h:27:21: note: candidate: static void fraction::outputFormat(fraction::fracForm)
         static void outputFormat(fracForm);
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
fraction.h:27:21: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘fracForm’ to ‘fraction::fracForm’
main.cpp:37:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘fraction::outputFormat(fracForm)’
    fraction::outputFormat(mixed); // set output format back to default mixed
                                ^
In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
fraction.h:27:21: note: candidate: static void fraction::outputFormat(fraction::fracForm)
         static void outputFormat(fracForm);
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
fraction.h:27:21: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘fracForm’ to ‘fraction::fracForm’
main.cpp:44:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘fraction::outputFormat(fracForm)’
    fraction::outputFormat(improper);
                                   ^
In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
fraction.h:27:21: note: candidate: static void fraction::outputFormat(fraction::fracForm)
         static void outputFormat(fracForm);
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
fraction.h:27:21: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘fracForm’ to ‘fraction::fracForm’
fraction.cpp:235:15: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘mix’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 fraction::mix() {
               ^
fraction.cpp:235:1: error: prototype for ‘int fraction::mix()’ does not match any in class ‘fraction’
 fraction::mix() {
 ^~~~~~~~
In file included from fraction.cpp:1:0:
fraction.h:69:16: error: candidate is: std::string fraction::mix()
         string mix();
                ^~~
fraction.cpp: In function ‘std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, fraction&)’:
fraction.cpp:250:12: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::istream& {aka std::basic_istream&}’ from expression of type ‘char’
     return i;
```

Comment: Please provide the full error messages

Comment: Please try to write [MRE], I mean minimal not maximal

Comment: I have posted the error messages. I don't know how to make it any more minimal.

Comment: Do you really expect us to read through ALL of this code? Detect the problem, isolate it, write a minimal example which shows where it goes wrong. That's your duty if you want us provide an answer.

Comment: Never do `using namespace std;` in header files. Never!

Comment: You defined fracForm  twice. one is global and one is in class. delete in class definiton or delete global definition and use your enums like fraction::improper.

Comment: @idris There's already an answer addressing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare the `enum fracForm` two times:

```
enum fracForm {improper, mixed, decimal};

class fraction {
    enum fracForm {improper, mixed, decimal};
```

The functions in class `fraction` are now using the enum `fraction::fracForm`, and the code outside (so in `main.cpp`) uses `fracForm`

These two `enums` aren't the same, so the code won't compile.

To solve the problem, you can use either the "`global`" approach, where fracForm is resolved from the `fraction` class:

```
enum fracForm {improper, mixed, decimal};

class fraction {
    //enum fracForm {improper, mixed, decimal};
```

With that solution, I would think most errors are gone.

The other solution would be, to put the fracForm error in the fraction class scope:

```
//enum fracForm {improper, mixed, decimal};

class fraction {
    public:
    enum fracForm {improper, mixed, decimal};
```

Now you have to use the enum outside the class like:

```
fracForm type = fraction::improper;
```

Comment: And `fraction::fracForm` is private too. It needs to be made public.

Comment: Depends on which type she wants to use, yes. I should specify that

Comment: So which one should I delete? I originally had it declared outside the class.

Comment: If you make a `fraction` namespace, leave it outside the class but in that namespace. If you don't, keep it in the class but make it public. That's my personal opinion and not a rule.

Comment: @khaleesi0712 if `fracForm` is mostly used with the class `fraction`, I think putting it in the class makes sense, because both come and go together. If you would use `fracForm` in another class (where you do not use `fraction`) use the global solution

Comment: This is the method that's getting the error `void fraction::outputFormat(fracForm fType) {
    fracForm format = fraction::fType;
}`

Comment: Yes, thank you, most of them are gone. It says undefined reference to fraction::format

Comment: Maybe make a new question with the remaining errors. Or better try to solve it by yourself at looking, why it doesnt find the definition of fraction::format

Comment: That's honestly the one error I've had several people look at today and I've been trying to find for 7 hours. I can't find it.